# Why curves are cumulated in the same plot? Why are they not plotted separately?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to save each resulted curve in one plot. However, the first curve is saved orrectly (I mean one curve), the second curve is added to the first curve then savec in an other plot. so the second plot gives me two curves, the third plot gives me three curves, that is wrong, I want that each curve is plotted lonely. by that way I can do my analysis.

```
   for b in range(0,16):
       tempSumDiff = np.zeros(len(tempTraces[0]))
            for i in range(9):
                for j in range(i):
                    tempSumDiff += np.abs(tempMeans[i] - tempMeans[j])

       plt.plot(tempSumDiff)
       plt.grid()
       plt.savefig('/local/home/Results_Picture/tempSumDiff_Byte_'+str(b)+'.png')
```

How do I correct  that please?

Comment: Your example is unclear. Please provide the correct indentation. Is the plot command part of the loop?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I correct it, the plot command  is the result of each loop iteration I mean that I must have 16 different  curves, in 16 different images

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To put your plot into a new figure, you need to create a new figure.

If you create a new figure, before you plot, you will obtain each plot in a new figure:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,2, 23)
data = np.random.normal(size=(len(x),9))

for i in range(9):
    plt.figure()  ### <=== create new figure
    plt.plot(x,data[:,i])
    #plt.savefig(...) #put savefig here, if needed.

plt.show()
```

Comment: he wants 16 different plots! so plt.show() should be inside the loop!

Comment: @alec_djinn If you run the code you get 9 plots. If you put `plt.show()` inside the loop you will need to close each figure individually before the next one is shown.

Comment: Yep, you are right, I didn't notice you create the figure in advance. I never do that, I just plot and save and it works.

Comment: I already wrote two sentences about creating a new figure. But I will replace the arrow `<---` by a bolder one `<===` if you want. The problem of using `plt.show()` would be that you actually **need** to show the figure, while in my answer above you could just leave the `plt.show()` out and just save the figures without showing them.

Answer (score -1):

Just add [plt.show()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=show#matplotlib.pyplot.show) before plt.savefig()